# Protected Package

Tags: packages

I found a package `Pack` that has this structure:

```
ClearAll["Pack2`*"];  
BeginPackage[ "Pack2`"]
...
Begin["`Private`"];
...
End[]
Protected["Pack2`"];
EndPackage[]
```

What does `` Protected["Pack2`"]; `` do at the whole package?
I read [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html), but it didn't help me.

Comment: ``Protected["Pack2`"];`` does nothing. I guess that the author of the package wanted to write ``Protect["Pack2`*"];``, but made a typo.

Comment: @Shadowray I think that is a guess worth an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record:

> `` Protected["Pack2`"]; `` does nothing. I guess that the author of the package wanted to write `` Protect["Pack2`*"]; ``, but made a typo.
>
> – Shadowray Jul 14 at 11:59

> `` Protect["context`*"] `` protects all symbols in a particular context.
>
> – ref/Protect